# Selecting folders located in different levels of the directory structure in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Is it possible to select folders located in different levels of the directory structure in Windows Explorer?

Example: how can I select the folders that the underlined in red in the screenshot below?

[image]

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: Are you selecting them to copy/delete?

Comment: @skv Most of the time, yes. I am trying to do it using the GUI (i.e. no cmd).

Comment: :) you got my idea... GUI IMHO  thats not possible, would wait for responses

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far, but I am still interested.